# Magento 2: Details and More Information tabs

Tags: magento2, product, additional-information

On one of the sample data products, it shows a More Information tab which, unsurprisingly, displays more information for the product. I've looked at the same product in the Admin area, but can't see where to add in the additional information for the tabs.

Anyone know where this information is added for each product?

Comment: Glad to see that with in 15 mins we got 4 answers.:-)

Comment: I Have a problem that "More Information" Hidden from product page.
From where can I reassign it again ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First Go to Admin panel,

Click on `Stores -> Attributes -> Product` from left side menu.

Click on Attribute you want to display inside details page.

Now click on `Storefront Properties` tab from left sidebar,
Set `Yes on Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront`.

`Details` tab display description of product, which is set from admin product.

Now your value display inside more information tab.
clear cache.

Answer (score 1):

@Mike

First tab is for **Details** and it comes from Description in product add/edit page from admin

And **More info** are related to product attribute which has visibility to Yes for **Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront front end**  which attribute has assign to current product

you can refer link to add attribute in [magento2 here](https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/magento2/product-attributes)

Hope this will work for you

*link is only for knowledge sharing purpose i am not associated with above  as of any*

Answer (score 1):

Go to the attribute which you want to show on Front end.

In admin **Stores**>**Attributes**>**Product**

There is tab Storefront Properties have drop-down "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" set it yes.

you should be able to see new attribute vale on Front-end.

Answer (score 1):

In product attribute option there is one option available `Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront` . If you set this option to yes then its value value will be display on product detail page under more information tab.

[image]